# Connect of a drop in range top

Tags: stove, range

The new range top has black, red and green.  The leads coming from box have red, black and white (neutral).    No green or bare out of box.  what to do with green out of range top and white out of box.

Comment: if it is a metal box (it should be grounded, connect the green to it

Comment: Include a picture of the opened box, showing the wires and where they come from, please. [Edit] it into the question.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?  This could be one of several things...